# How to set rich:calendar (RichFaces) value with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I have a rich:calendar component and now i want to change the value of these components with JQuery. I use Rich Faces Version 3.3.*

But this command doesn't work:

```
jQuery('#editForm:SomeDate').val('23.11.2014');
```

Is there a way, to change value of this component with JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using RF-3 anymore (so can't really check), but [this forum thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/200207) points out the best solution, IMHO:

```
#{rich:component('editForm:SomeDate').setValue('23.11.2014');
```

Have a look at the [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#rich_calendar), specifically Table 6.163. JavaScript API for more useful methods.

Comment: Is that the correct syntax for a suitable JQuery command?: jQuery('#{rich:component('editForm:SomeDate')}').setValue('23.11.2014');

Comment: @Marwief no, `#{rich:component(..)}` will render the correct javascript to get your object. No additional `jQuery` calls needed.

Comment: Sorry, but that code doesn´t work in my js file: #{rich:component('editForm:SomeDate')}.setValue('23.11.2014');

Comment: @Marwief Yeah, the `#{}` is an EL-expression. That only gets evaluated in JSF templates. Try putting it in a `<script>` section in your template.

Comment: In which template? Do you mean the jsf page or my js file?

Comment: @Marwief the JSF page is also called a JSF template, so the former.